# WSL2 Docker Flask container doesn't connects

Tags: python, docker, flask, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to create a simple web application container within Ubuntu-WSL2 with the help of the Docker. So I've built my container creating my-simple-webapp folder and within that folder, I've created Dockerfile and app.py files;

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python python-pip
RUN pip install flask
COPY app.py /opt/
ENTRYPOINT FLASK_APP=/opt/app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080
```

app.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

@app.route('/how are you')
def hello():
    return 'I am good, how about you?'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

When I run the command `docker build ./my-simple-webapp` it works without error. However when I use my browser to connect my container typing `172.17.0.2:8080`, `o.o.o.o:8080` or `localhost:8080` connection times out.

Resource : https://github.com/mmumshad/simple-webapp-flask

Answer (score 1):

If all you run is `docker build...` then you still need to start your container with `docker run...`.

You can open the docker dashboard (in your Windows tray) to see if your container is actually running.

Answer (score 1):

To actually run your app you need to start a container. First, build the image:

`docker build -t simple-webapp-flask .`

Then start a container using the image, with 8080:8080 mapping from container to your host:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 simple-webapp-flask`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy your flask application, you need to choose from the following options:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/

The way you are trying to do it, can be used only for development purposes.